# Emacs viewmail imap

Tags: email, emacs, imap, virtual-machine, stunnel

Anybody is using viewmail on OS X? I'm trying to use it, but after installing stunnel 4.35 using macport, when I try to visit my imap inbox, i got the following error:

IMAP protocol error: "unexpected char (10)"

I googled it, but so far no solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Several users have reported that stunnel 4.33 works on Mac OS X, and later versions don't.  Your best bet is to stick to stunnel 4.33 for as long as you can.

Alternatively, Emacs 24 (on prerelease) and VM 8.2.0b (beta release) have built-in support for SSL.  You can set `vm-stunnel-program' to nil to get the built-in support.

You can see this [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/vm/+bug/815267) for more info.

This [page on wiredbytes.com](http://wiredbytes.com/node/8) gives a simple procedure for testing your stunnel program.